# Hints for Cambridge Mathematical Tripos 2014 Countability Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question has three parts:

(i) What does it mean to say that a set X is countable? Show directly that the set of sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, with $x_n \in \{0,1\}$ for all $n$, is uncountable.

(ii) Let $S$ be any subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Show that there exists a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(S) = 2\mathbb{N}$ (the set of even natural numbers) if and only if both $S$ and its complement are infinite.

(iii) Let $\sqrt2 = 1.a_1a_2a_3...$ be the binary expansion of $\sqrt2$. Let $X$ be the set of all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in \{0,1\}$ such that for infinitely many $n, x_n =0$. Let $Y$ be the set of all $(x_n) \in X$ such that for infinitely many $n$, $x_n = a_n$. Show that $Y$ is uncountable.

I am fine with part (i) and (ii) but I need some guidance for part (iii). Any hints which can point me in the right direction would be great, and I will solve on my own using the hints and follow up. Thanks.

Comment: Infinitely many $a_n$ must have value $1$. You could show that the set of binary sequences with infinitely many zeroes and infinitely many ones is uncountable. This will imply $Y$ is uncountable.

Comment: Consider sequences of the type $$a_1,0,b_1,a_4,0,b_4,a_7,0,b_7,\dots$$ This agrees with $a_i$ on infinitely many positions, is $0$ on infinitely many positions, and you can fill in the $b_i$ however you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the binary expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ we have $a_n = 0$ for infinitely many $n$, because otherwise  $\sqrt{2}$ would be rational : infact in this case we could write $$\sqrt{2} = q + \sum_{i=N}^{+ \infty} \biggl( \frac{1}{2} \biggr)^i$$ with $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus the sequence $\lbrace a_n \rbrace_n $ is in $X$, and the set $H = \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \ |\ a_n = 0 \rbrace $ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.

It is well known that $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, is uncountable; instead the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. Thus the set of all infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

For every infinite subset $K$ of $H$ we obtain at least one sequence $\lbrace y_n \rbrace $ in $Y$ in the following way $$y_n = 0 \ \text{if} \ n \in K $$ $$y_n = 1 \ \text{if} \ n \not\in K$$ These sequences are in bijection with the infinite subsets of $H$, and thus $Y $ is uncountable.